# How to search massive no of files for a search term in most efficient way?

Tags: java, multithreading

Using `Lucene` is forbidden.I have a single computer with 8 cores & 20 GB RAM. I have 1 million NFS files.I have to search for a search term say "Hello World". My questions are:

What should be the most efficient way?

How many threads to spawn?

And if I have multiple computers at my disposal, what way the answer changes? I will do this with java.
Say I use a [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html). What should be its corePoolSize? maximumPoolSize? I want to submit [Callable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) tasks to it which will read the file & using regex search for desired search term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quote from the book *Programming Concurrency on the JVM* by Venkat Subramaniam, regarding how to calculate the optimum size for your thread pool:

```
Number of threads = Number of Available Cores / (1 - Blocking Coefficient)
```

> where the blocking coefficient is between 0 and 1.

The *blocking coefficient* is the percentage of time a single thread is blocked, i.e. waiting for something like disk I/O. So if that percent is, for example, 30, then your *blocking coefficient* will be `0.3`

Comment: That was helpful. Is there any rule of thumb for blocking coefficient? Or I have to find that out in action ( running top command etc which will give me CPU usage.

Comment: Again quoting from the same book: _We can try to guess it, or we can use profiling tools or the java.lang.management API to determine the amount of time a thread spends on system/IO operations_