# Efficiently using threads with multicore processors

Tags: java, multithreading

Let's say I have a quad core system (without hyperthreading) and I'm building a program in java (that's an unchangeable restriction) that must process a set of large files as quickly as possible. Would it be fastest to process the files if I restrict the number of processing threads to the number of cores on the system that runs the program (4 in this example case)? Does this ensure that the load will be spread among all the cores or does it not matter what I do because the scheduler will do what it thinks is best for the load?

Comment: The exact number of threads to use relative to the number of cores seems to be an endless debate. I've seen everything from `n = n_cores` to `n = n_cores + 2` to `n = n_cores * 2`. In my testing for a certain application, there doesn't seem to be a whole lot of difference, although too many threads degrades performance.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54721198/how-to-search-massive-no-of-files-for-a-search-term-in-most-efficient-way/54724790#54724790) answer. Perhaps it may help - assuming you haven't already seen it.

Comment: If your task is primarily I/O bound (as reading large files would normally be), then adapting the number of threads to the number of processors is hardly relevant. If anything, any parallelization advise depends more on your I/O solution. For example, if your files are on a mechanical hard drive, then it's probably wiser to process one file at a time, to avoid seeking. If they are located on SSD storage, you should probably benchmark your SSD for the queue depth it performs optimally at, and choose your number of threads after that.